# Temporary assigning NULL to a value for the purpose of sorting values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the correct formatting of results back from a Mysql query.  When I ignore the NULL values, the formatting is correct, but when I allow null values to be included, my results are messed up.

I have the following query I am using:

```
select name,suite,webpagetest.id,MIN(priority) AS min_pri 
FROM webpagetest,comparefileerrors 
WHERE vco="aof" AND user="1" AND calibreversion="9" 
AND webpagetest.id=comparefileerrors.id 
AND comparefileerrors.priority IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY coalesce(priority,suite,name) ASC;
```

This returns the expected output:

```
    +-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+---------+
| name                        | suite                       | id    | min_pri |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+---------+
| set_get_status              | shortsRepairDB_2009.1_suite |  6193 |       0 | 
| u2uDemo                     | shortsRepairDB_2009.1_suite |  6195 |       0 | 
| change_sets                 | shortsRepairDB_2009.1_suite |  6194 |       0 | 
| bz1508_SEGV_password        | NULL                        |  6185 |       1 | 
| assign_short_AND_user_info  | shortsRepairDB_2009.1_suite |  6198 |       2 | 
| bz1273_cmdline_execplussvdb | NULL                        |  6203 |       2 | 
| bz1747_bad_lvsf             | NULL                        | 36683 |       3 | 
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+---------+
```

However, sometimes the priority values will not be set.  If this is the case, I want the database to treat the priority as if it had an extremely high priority, so that the values with a null-priority are at the very bottom.  I can not set the priority ahead of time (using a default value), but for the purposes of the sort, is it possible to do this?

Currently, if I issue the following command,

```
select name,suite,webpagetest.id,MIN(priority) AS min_pri 
FROM webpagetest,comparefileerrors 
WHERE vco="aof" AND user="1" AND calibreversion="9" 
AND webpagetest.id=comparefileerrors.id 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY coalesce(priority,suite,name) ASC;
```

I get output like the following:

```
| name                        | suite | id    | min_pri |
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+---------+
| bz1747_bad_lvsf             | NULL  | 36683 |       1 | 
| NEC_Dragon.query            | NULL  | 36684 |    NULL | 
| avago_hwk_elam0_asic        | NULL  |  6204 |    NULL | 
| bz1273_cmdline_execplussvdb | NULL  |  6203 |       2 | 
| bz1491_query_server_crash   | NULL  |  6188 |    NULL | 
| bz1493_export_built_in_prop | NULL  |  6186 |    NULL | 
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.68 sec)
```

Here I have lost the formatting I had before.  I would like the formatting to be as follows:

```
| name                        | suite | id    | min_pri |
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+---------+
| bz1747_bad_lvsf             | NULL  | 36683 |       0 | 
| NEC_Dragon.query            | NULL  | 36684 |       0 |
| avago_hwk_elam0_asic        | NULL  |  6204 |       1 | 
| bz1273_cmdline_execplussvdb | NULL  |  6203 |       2 | 
| bz1491_query_server_crash   | NULL  |  6188 |    NULL | 
| bz1493_export_built_in_prop | NULL  |  6186 |    NULL | 
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.68 sec)
```

Hopefully I've explained this well enough that someone can understand what I want here.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want `MIN(IFNULL(priority, 99999))`.  See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) for the `IFNULL()` function.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I ended up using!  It was so simple!

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to use sentinel value, i.e. ORDER BY COALESCE(priority, 99999); use:

```
select * from x 
order by 

    case 
    when priority is not null then 1 /* non-nulls, first */ 
    else 2 /* nulls last */ 
    end, 

    priority
```

or you can take advantage of the fact that mysql boolean expression results to either 1 or 0:

```
select * from x 
order by priority is null, priority
```

or if you're using postgresql:

```
select * from x order by priority nulls first
```

alternatively:

```
select * from x order by priority nulls last
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't end up using this, but I used the order by logic in other statements I was using..  I didn't realize you could have cases in order statements